# Can I tap on the phone screen when I'm out of the app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm learning react-native for this i try to make app like auto clicker with "react-native" but i think is bad thing bec i try to how can click the phone display but i'm search about it for 8 hours but i cant find.

I try to search about package do something like this but i can't find or i find but it's work only in the app and i try to ask chatgpt 3.5, bard, you chat and other but all give me codes dosent work and cant fix it.

This code only work in app. (I'm not sure if is work or not but when i leave the app "console" stop send data.)

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { GestureHandlerRootView, TapGestureHandler, State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const App = () => {
  const handleRandomTap = () => {

    setTimeout(() => {
      const tapEvent = {
        nativeEvent: {
          x: 1000,
          y: 1000,
          state: State.ACTIVE,
        },
      };
      console.log(tapEvent)

      tapRef.current.setNativeProps(tapEvent);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const tapRef = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.container}>
      <TapGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={handleRandomTap}>
        <View style={styles.randomClick} ref={tapRef} />
      </TapGestureHandler>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  randomClick: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderRadius: 50,
  },
});

export default App;
```

I'm use

```
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
    "NODE-VERSION": "v16.20.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The option of tapping applications outside your own application is a major security flaw. A malicious app could hyopthetically open your bank app and start wiring money.

That's why you're not finding anything. And all OS's will go to lengths to prevent it.

However, having developed an app for people with severe motor disabilities, I came across an Accessibility Service API on Android that lets you [dispatch gestures](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#dispatchGesture(android.accessibilityservice.GestureDescription,%20android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) across the entire system.

The use case there is to tap applications on behalf of the user who cannot do it him/herself.

Don't think it's available in react-native though, but no expert there :)

Comment: I think it is in Android Studio but i dont want learn new langaue like kotlin or java.. :)